# Why does SU allow me to change my display name without confirmation and limits further changes?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-bydesign, user-accounts, username

Recently, I was editing my profile, typing something, and an advertisement frame popped up, for lack of better name, since y'all are sparing on the ads.   The 'frame' somehow caused my cursor focus to shift and it seems that I inadvertantly added 'te' to the beginning of my Display Name.

(I have no REAL idea what happened, something appeared, and I lost focus, had to click to regain.  Yes, Vague.  My apologies)

I do understand WHY you have a time limit on further changes to prevent people from confusing things with frequent name changes, but I feel there should be some sort of confirmation before the change is allowed to prevent occurrences like mine.

Kinda weird being 'telornix', but as the little balloon says, June 29th, I can change it back. (Yay!)

Please consider adding a confirmation for any profile information with a limited change frequency such as the Display Name.  (There may be others, I'm not going looking...)

Comment: I think the hardest part is coming up with the QUESTION.  It's like playing Jeopardy... "Please phrase your answer as a question..."

Comment: Sounds fair enough. By the way, I'm fairly sure a moderator can revert your name change.

Comment: You should be able to edit your profile (*not* changing your still correct user name) on any other Stack Exchange site, and select "Save and Copy Profile to All Stack Exchange Accounts".

Comment: Aha! Sneak up on the problem.  I'll give that a try.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> an advertisement frame popped up

No idea what that was, but we don't do popup ads (it's not clear from your question whether you were assuming this came from us).

> there should be some sort of confirmation

Wherever possible, we tend to go with the [no need to confirm if you can undo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163835.aspx) philosophy. That's why within 15 minutes of your change, you would have been able to change the name back; only then is the name locked in for a month. I consider 15 minutes to be enough to notice an accidental name change; why it took you almost three weeks to notice it is, to be honest, a little beyond me :)

> Kinda weird being 'telornix',

I have removed the "te"; you shall once more be known as lornix.

Comment: wasn't an advert, just something, possibly delayed due to download delay or something.  dunno.  It happened.  My fault ultimately.   And wasn't 3 weeks to notice, I'd picked it up within an hour or so, been trying to fix it since.  I just wasn't aware the characters had been inserted.  I claim full responsibility there.  Thank you for fixing me.  (I was broke?)

Comment: took 3 weeks for me to decide my question was worth bothering the gods.  The meta-site content seems to much 'above' my petty name change.  I was willing to wait the 30 days.  Again, thank you.

Comment: No problem! Also note that the Super User moderators are fairly active on chat (they even have a [Ask a Mod room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator)), so for some smaller issues (like this one), you have a good chance of getting quick responses there.

Comment: As a late update... I figured out what caused my cursor/caret focus to change... I use 'pentadactyl', the 'vim-for-firefox' add-on.  I had just started Firefox, and as it usually does, it tried to update the add-ons... pentadactyl updated and restarted itself, but when it did this time, there was a hiccup and I got a message (on its cmd line), which tweaked my cursor. (caret, not mouse).  So yeah, no ads (yay for you!), just my own system plotting against me.